"Contest" labor law loophole
I was watching the TV show Alone, and it got me thinking. I think the show pits 10 contestants against each other in a survival competition, where the last person standing wins $500,000. But it struck me as a bit one-sided— the network ends up with nine people who create entertaining, watchable content essentially for free, and only one person gets the big prize.
That got me wondering: what if I were a ruthless, profit-driven businessman? Could I, for instance, set up a “contest” where 20 people spend two days in a warehouse packing boxes, with the promise that whoever packs the most wins $10,000..(essentially I get free labor from 19 people for 2 days and then only pay one person $10,000)?

Interns are exactly that, and in many countries they still allow unpaid internships.

People are also free to volunteer their time at non profit organizations.  Anyway, why not?  If I go to a carnival and play a ring toss game to win a stuffed toy they don't pay me for trying.  Does the actual activity matter?

You could get 20 people for two days for less than $3000 with normal pay. Not a great hypothetical.

@littleadv Conversely, in many countries, interns must be paid if they are doing actual work (as opposed to learning stuff, shadowing employees, or doing other non-work-related activities), although rules for charities may be different. (UK.) France has a minimum wage for interns depending on how long they are working for.

@StuartF right. What was the point of your comment?

The cast members are all being paid. Of course the winner gets paid much more, or gets some other benefit, but it is not free labour from everyone else. For Alone, it may be $1,000 to $2,000 per week.
When they're not paid enough, that exposes the production company to liability. Your "warehouse contest" hypothetical would run into the same liability.

Yes, pretty much universally around the world, reality TV contestants are paid the minimum wage for the work they are doing.

A better hypothetical might be Squid Game. Not only did the losers not get paid, they were killed (oops, forgot to say "spoiler alert").

france
Statute
The statutory basis for what is a work contract is rather thin: article L1221-1 of the labor code

Le contrat de travail est soumis aux règles du droit commun. Il peut être établi selon les formes que les parties contractantes décident d'adopter.


The work contract is subject to standard contract law. It may be established under whatever forms the contracting parties choose.

This simply says that it does not need be to be a written document with a header that says "work contract" to be valid. But it does not say whether the hypothetical "box-packing contest" is a work contract. So we must turn to jurisprudence.
Case law
The standard case for what constitutes a work contract is Cour de Cassation du 13 novembre 1996, 94-13.187:

[Attendu que] sont considérées comme rémunérations toutes les sommes versées aux travailleurs en contrepartie ou à l'occasion d'un travail accompli dans un lien de subordination ; que le lien de subordination est caractérisé par l'exécution d'un travail sous l'autorité d'un employeur qui a le pouvoir de donner des ordres et des directives, d'en contrôler l'exécution et de sanctionner les manquements de son subordonné ; que le travail au sein d'un service organisé peut constituer un indice du lien de subordination lorsque l'employeur détermine unilatéralement les conditions d'exécution du travail ;


Wages [for the purpose of social security law] consist of all sums given to workers for work accomplished under a link of subordination. The link of subordination is characterized by work executed under the authority of an employer that can give orders, control their execution and discipline the subordinate worker for their failure. Work within an organised team may be a clue to the existence of a subordination link when the employer decides unilaterally the conditions under which work is executed.

(Old-style opinions of the Cour de Cassation are a single long run-on sentence of "the court, given that X, given that Y, but given that Z ... decides that ...". I simplified this in the translation.)
This has been a fairly stable criterion, used in particular to decide that "reality TV" contestants are in fact employees: Cour de cassation du 24 avril 2013, 11-19.091 and others (not citing all case numbers, because there were lots of parties with separate procedures):

Mais attendu que l'existence d'une relation de travail ne dépend ni de la volonté exprimée par les parties ni de la dénomination qu'elles ont donnée à leur convention mais des conditions de fait dans lesquelles est exercée l'activité des travailleurs ;
Et attendu qu'ayant constaté qu'il existait entre les membres de l'équipe de production et les participants un lien de subordination caractérisé par l'existence d'une « bible » prévoyant le déroulement des journées et la succession d'activités filmées imposées, de mises en scènes dûment répétées, d'interviews dirigées de telle sorte que l'interviewé était conduit à dire ce qui était attendu par la production, que ce lien de subordination se manifestait encore par le choix des vêtements par la production, des horaires imposés allant jusqu'à vingt heures par jour, l'obligation de vivre sur le site et l'impossibilité de se livrer à des occupations personnelles, (...) ;


However, the existence of a work relationship does not depend on the will expressed by the parties or the name they gave to their convention. It rather depends on the factual conditions under which the workers’ activity is performed.
[The appeals court] established that the participants were subordinated to the production, by the existence of a "bible" detailing the day schedule and the succession of mandatory filmed activities, of rehearsed scenes, of interviews directed in a way that the participant would say what the production expected. The subordination was also manifest in the clothing (chosen by the production); in the existence of mandatory work times up to twenty hours a day; in the obligation to live onsite and the impossibility to get on personal errands; (etc. etc.)
(...)

...which is why they are now paid (usually minimum wage).
The more common case law nowadays is "gig economy" cases. See for instance this interview from 2020 (by a lawyer who won a court case against Uber, but provides a decent panorama of such decisions).
Your hypothetical
In your box-packing contest, you would presumably

provide the time and place where the packing should take place
order which item should go into which box, and in which order items should be packed
define clear pick-up and drop-off points, and other rules allowing you to make use of the packed boxes
reprimand, kick out or financially penalize any "contestant" who packed boxes improperly

All of those are fairly clear clues that the "contestants" are in fact workers under your direction. You would therefore fall under the various laws around minimum wage, maximum work hours and so on.
